# how to set width 50% inside bootstrap input group

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

set width 50% each in select tag and remaing part

```
  
    <div class="input-group">
      <select class="form-select">
        <option selected value="dummy">Dummy</option>
        <option selected value="rd">Random data</option>
      </select>
      <span class="input-group-text bg-theme">Selection</span>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control dropdown-toggle"
          data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
          readonly
        />
        <div class="dropdown-menu p-0 w-100">
          <div class="list-group">
            <label class="list-group-item">
              <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="checkbox" checked />
              dummy
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

How can i make select tag with 50% width and remaing part also 50% width ?

Comment: Maybe you should set the `d-inline-flex flex-wrap` class to `.input-group` element and then use an `flex-basis` property to each child of  `.input-group` with `width` you need?

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use the BS5 grid system in order to change the size.

```html
<div class="row g-2">
  <div class="col-md">
    <div class="form-floating">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="floatingInputGrid" placeholder="name@example.com" value="mdo@example.com">
      <label for="floatingInputGrid">Email address</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md">
    <div class="form-floating">
      <select class="form-select" id="floatingSelectGrid">
        <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
      </select>
      <label for="floatingSelectGrid">Works with selects</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]